# If an element doesn't have a font-size, give it one

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create something in jquery that will add a default font-size to every element on the page if it doesn't already have one.

How would I do that?

Comment: Why not just do it in CSS?  Much simpler.

Comment: Hey, WHY don't you do this in CSS? :)

Comment: Asking this question means you've missed the whole point of ***Cascading*** _Style Sheets_.  You need to go back and research/learn what the "cascading" part means.  It is intended to avoid doing things the way you are asking, by using inheritance to provide values for rendering attributes such as font size.

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery. Just use the css [universal](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/universal-selector-css-selector/) selector like

```
*{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for this.

```
body {
    font-size: 14px; /* Or whatever size you want */
}
```

Comment: The table element will not inherit this.

Comment: Interesting.  Then I will modify that to "The table element will not always inherit this."  It may be specific to earlier IE versions.  I've been doing a lot in the IE 7 engine (windows gadgets) lately and <table> will not inherit a font-size set on <body>.

Comment: IE7...  sorry to hear that :)

Comment: lol, thanks.  I wish there was a way to update the gadget engine.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on CSS Resets.  With a little research you'll see how to set a default font size that can be flexibly overridden in ways that you can easily control.  You'll prefer to do this in CSS, and perhaps use JS to make unique localized modifications, if anything.  Most of your style markup can and should be in CSS.